# How to display decimal equivalent (0-63) on two 7-segment displays using 6 switches as bits?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, quartus

I recently did a skills test wherein the problem was described as: 
"Create a .v (verilog hdl) file that uses sw [6:1] to represent 0 to 63  in the 7-segment displays hex2 and hex1 while showing "--" for any number divisible by 4."

I finished it by hardcoding (since I was under a time limit) all the values using a case statement from 0-63 taking note of those divisible by 4 to show just "--"

Of course that isn't the optimal solution and I hate to leave a problem solved by means of hardcoding values.

This is for a Cyclone-II FPGA (what we have in university) and am using Quartus II to compile. For the "--" for every number divisible by 4, I solved it by adding a conditional operator and did "(sw % 4) == 0 ? n : ...". I've done the hardcoding and my attempt to solve it another way by taking note of the pattern for every 16 intervals and "shifting up" the value of the 7-segment display to what '0000' is for that value (at 16, 10000 = h6, 17 10001 = h7, etc.):

```
module sk10(sw,hex1,hex2,hex3,hex0);
input [5:0] sw;
output [6:0] hex1,hex2,hex3 = 7'h7F, hex0 = 7'h7F; 

reg [6:0] hex1;

parameter h0 = 7'b0000001; 
parameter h1 = 7'b1001111;
parameter h2 = 7'b0010010; 
parameter h3 = 7'b0000110;
parameter h4 = 7'b1001100;
parameter h5 = 7'b0100100;
parameter h6 = 7'b0100000;
parameter h7 = 7'b0001111;
parameter h8 = 7'b0000000;
parameter h9 = 7'b0000100;
parameter n =  7'b1111110;

assign hex2 = (sw % 4 == 0) ? n :
                    (sw < 10) ? h0 : 
                    (sw < 20 && sw >= 10) ? h1 :
                    (sw < 30 && sw >= 20) ? h2 :
                    (sw < 40 && sw >= 30) ? h3 :
                    (sw < 50 && sw >= 40) ? h4 :
                    (sw < 60 && sw >= 50) ? h5 :
                    (sw < 70 && sw >= 60 ) ? h6 : n;

always @ (sw)
begin
    if (sw < 16) begin 
            case (sw[3:0])
            0 : hex1 = h0; 
            1 : hex1 = h1;
            2 : hex1 = h2; 
            3 : hex1 = h3;
            4 : hex1 = h4;
            5 : hex1 = h5;
            6 : hex1 = h6;
            7 : hex1 = h7;
            8 : hex1 = h8;
            9 : hex1 = h9;
            10 : hex1 = h0;
            11 : hex1 = h1;
            12 : hex1 = h2;
            13 : hex1 = h3;
            14 : hex1 = h4;
            15 : hex1 = h5;
            endcase
            end
    else if (sw >= 16 && sw < 32) begin
            case (sw[3:0])
            0 : hex1 = h6; 
            1 : hex1 = h7;
            2 : hex1 = h8; 

... and so on for every 16 intervals until 64
```

It works but it is hardly optimal and I might as well have hardcoded all 64 case statements since this new, alternative code I made is longer than that. I'd like to ask for help for a better alternative than hardcoding each one or my attempt above. Any answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result is for displaying, it should be acceptable to spend some clock cycles to get the result.

Check the ["double dabble"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) algorithm.

Nanland site has some examples too: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/double-dabble.html

Comment: Hmm, our instructor mentioned that the code should work as if its a decoder/combinatorial circuit i.e. no clock, just using sensitivity lists as in using an always block with the switches input ports as argument. Would it be possible with the above previous specifications?

Comment: Alright, thank you for pointing me to something & taking time to answer I won't ask anymore of you. But it isn't hw; I already stated that I'm only trying to know how to do it properly under the specifications above (which I don't think was possible under 20 minutes w/o prior research) rather than what I did. I'm sorry if it came off as if I'm asking for h.w. answers (I'm not used to asking) but this was posted 3 days ago: if it's hw, the deadline would've long passed. I was just hoping to get some help and tried my best to be specific w/ the questions(being clueless about it) Thanks again.